# How to set xml value to an escape character in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, escaping

I need to set an xml value to the newline escape code

```
<Variable>Foo &#xA; Bar</Variable>
```

I'm using get-content to create an xml object and trying to assign the variable using the following method

```
$qux = $("Foo &#xA; Bar")
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $xmlpath)

$xml.Variable = $qux 

$xml.Save($tlpath)
$xml.Close
```

I've tried using &amp in place of &, using single quotes and a backslash and I can't seem to prevent the code from converting the & to &amp and spitting out the following xml

```
<Variable>Foo &amp;#xA; Bar</Variable>
```

What is the best way to get around powershell converting the escape character?

Comment: .Net XML class [saves \n as actual new lines inside text nodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.newlinehandling(v=vs.110).aspx). Why do you need it as an entity?

Answer (score 1):

Assign a normal multiline string:

```
$xml.Variable = "Foo`nBar"
```

Or access the variable as an XML node and assign an XML string which will be transformed into normal newline characters:

```
$xml['Variable'].innerXml = "Foo&#xA;Bar"
```

.NET framework XML class saves new line characters as actual new lines [inside text nodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.newlinehandling(v=vs.110).aspx), and as entities when inside attributes. It means that we'll need to postprocess the XML output before writing it:

```
$xml = [xml]::new()
$xml.Load('r:\1.xml')

$xml.Variable = "Foo`nBar"

# encode &#xD; inside text nodes and both &#xA; &#xD; inside attributes
$xmlSettings = [Xml.XmlWriterSettings]::new()
$xmlSettings.NewLineHandling = [Xml.NewLineHandling]::Entitize 
$sb = [Text.StringBuilder]::new()
$xmlWriter = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create($sb, $xmlSettings)
$xml.Save($xmlWriter)

$sb.ToString().Replace("`n", '&#xA;') | Out-File r:\2.xml -Encoding utf8
```

Note: in PowerShell 2.0 instead of `[some.class]::new()` use `New-Object some.class`

Comment: I received a "Cannot find type XML.XMLWriterSettings" when I tried to execute this and setting the variable through .innerXml didn't work unfortunately

Comment: I'm using PowerShell 5.1 and the new NET framework. Well, you can always simply read the xml file as text and replace the new lines `(get-content 2.xml) -join '&#xA;' | out-file ......`